# How can I use '::' operation in this case?

Tags: java, lambda

I want to know how to convert lambda expression printing string length to using '::' operation.

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"1", "234", "56"};
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.length()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question! Here you could do so **twice**. Once to map each `String` to an `int` by calling `length()` on each `String` and a second time by calling `println(int)` on `System.out`. Like,

```
Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(String::length).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I can get same output when I use map instead of mapToInt. I know that map returns Stream<T> and mapToInt return IntStream. There is any advantage using mapToInt instead of using map?

Comment: @orubt Yes. Using `map` involves `Integer` (the wrapper type). The primitives types in Java are generally more performant. Why use the `Integer` wrapper when you don't have to?